# How move Child Nodes along with values to grand parent node

Tags: xml, xslt, nodes, parent

I tried few different ways to transfer all child nodes to grand parent, pattern match is happening to only one child node but not recursively. Appreciate any help here.

```
<grandparent1>
    <parent1>
        <child1>1</child1>
        <child2>2</child2>
    </parent2>
</grandparent1>
```

Should become

```
<grandparent1>
    <child1>1</child1>
    <child2>2</child2>
</grandparent1>
```

Size of child nodes varies.
Appreciate any help here

Comment: What language are you programming with. if there is any code, can you provide that? BTW, you have <parent1> at the top while <parent2> at bottom.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to do using XSLT's recursive [processing model](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#section-Processing-Model).

First, use the *identity transform* template to recursively copy everything *as is*. Then add an exception for the parent nodes and make them continue the recursion without copying themselves.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="parent1 | parent2">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To make this generic for any parent (i.e. 2nd level) node, without knowing its name in advance, you could use:

```
<xsl:template match="/*/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

as the second template.